# jQTouch no longer supports Android?

Tags: jquery, android, cordova, android-webview, jqtouch

I have a stripped down page using jQTouch (jQTouch-1.0-b4-rc) from jqtouch.com that refuses to work with the Android 4 WebView (phonegap/cordova, ICS browser, etc...).  It works great in many other browsers (iOS, Safari, FF, Chrome, IE) but after loading fails to navigate on Android 4, suggesting jQTouch is incompatible with Android.  The page loads, but the navigation doesn't work.  I have reproduced this on two different phones and in the emulator.  It's consistently broken.   Check it out:

http://workgroup.ca/jqt_fails_on_android/

I've tried using jQTouch with zepto and jquery 1.4.2, 1.7.0, and 1.7.2 and I really don't think that's the problem as it works as expected in every other browser.  I think jQTouch is no longer compatible with the Android webkit WebView.  I've been testing on Android 4.0.3 and 4.0.4.  It fails on two devices and in the emulator using the default browser, chrome beta, and PhoneGap.

Can someone please take a look this stripped down page and show me an error, or confirm that jQTouch no longer supports Android.

To that end does anyone actually have a jQTouch application working on Android 4?  If so, what's the URL and what file versions are working for you?

Thanks,

Murray

Comment: Just found my answer.  

jQTouch on android requires useFastTouch: false  

`code`var jQT = new $.jQTouch({
   statusBar: 'black',
   useFastTouch: false
});

Comment: `jQT = new $.jQTouch({
 statusBar: 'black', 
  useFastTouch: false });`

Comment: Thanks. This really helped me. You should put this in the "Answer" section so it will be easier to find :) . +1

Answer (score 4):

Just putting moxy's comment in the "Answer" section.

jQTouch on android requires `useFastTouch: false`

```
var jQT = new $.jQTouch({ 
      statusBar: 'black', 
      useFastTouch: false 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried using your application on my Android phone.  Pantech Burst.  It works perfectly fine.  Not sure if you've changed it by now or what.